# Angular 2 Http with promise issue

Tags: angular

i am try to create a login app using angular 2 http with promise.

```
issue is before printing the response object in extractData function in service, "Got response" console is printing from login component.
```

So before am getting response from my restful webservice login component below code are executes. This happening only first time i click sign in button. Second time onwards am getting response first then login component code are executes.

Please someone help me to how to wait till response come from webservice.

```
please find my code below.

Login component

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';

import {User} from '../model/user';
import {UserService} from '../service/user-service';

@Component({
    selector : 'login-form',
    templateUrl : 'app/template/login.html',
    providers : [
        UserService
    ]
})

export class LoginComponent{

    user: User;

    constructor(private userService: UserService,private router: Router){}

    loginUser(form: any): void {  
        this.userService.loginUser(form.username,form.password).then(user => this.user = user)
        console.log("Got response");
        //console.log(this.user);
        try {
            console.log(this.user.userID);
            console.log(this.user.name);
            console.log(this.user.mobile);
            console.log(this.user.email);
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
        catch(err) {
        }
  }
}

And my service 

import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import '../rxjs-operators';

import {User} from '../model/user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService{

    private userUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/khalibottle/user/';
    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    constructor(private http:Http){}

    getUsers (): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.userUrl + "list")
                  .toPromise()
                  .then(this.extractData)
                  .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    loginUser (userName,password): Promise<User> {
       let body = JSON.stringify({ userName, password });
       let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
       return this.http.post(this.userUrl + "login",body,options)
                  .toPromise()
                  .then(this.extractData)
                  .catch(this.handleError);
   }

   registerUser (name,mobile,email,password,roleID): Promise<string> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ name, mobile, email, password, roleID });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    return this.http.post(this.userUrl + "register",body,options)
                  .toPromise()
                  .then(this.extractData)
                  .catch(this.handleError);
  }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
      console.log(body);
        return body || { };
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Take the code that you want to wait before executing, and put it inside the `.then()` call on the promise. Anything and everything that is outside `.then()` (or `.catch()`, etc.) will never wait. The success you're seeing on the second and later clicks is an illusion, each time using the results of the previous call.

Like this:

```
    loginUser(form: any): void {  
        this.userService.loginUser(form.username, form.password).then(user => {
            this.user = user;
            console.log("Got response");
            //console.log(this.user);
            try {
                console.log(this.user.userID);
                console.log(this.user.name);
                console.log(this.user.mobile);
                console.log(this.user.email);
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }
            catch(err) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function to retain `this`

```
.then((val) => this.extractData(val))
```

instead of

```
.then(this.extractData)
```

This would also work

```
.then(this.extractData.bind(this))
```